# Ruby on rails - API add status route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, routes

Im building an API on rails and im new in this framework. I want to add a status route to the API.
For example, running in local, if i make a request to endpoint: GET /status (http://localhost:3000/status)  it should have to return status code 204, just that.

How can i do it?

I was thinking of creating a model called status and just use the index method, rendering status: :204, but I think there has to be an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need a model, just a controller to handle the request. In config/routes.rb you configure `get '/status', to: 'status#index'` where `status#index` is the index method in your `StatusController`. The index method just returns the desired response, e.g. `head 204`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a `Status` model in this example.

Add a new routes to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resource :status, only: [:show] # note the singular `resource` instead `resources`
```

And add a new controller at `app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb` (plural here) with this content;

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    head :no_content
  end
end
```